# Distance transform .NET

Tags: c#, .net, math

Does anybody know where can I find a .NET library that computes distance transform of an image with exact euclidean distances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Emgu library](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) does that. The library is  .NET version for OpenCV

Answer (score 1):

You may also check out [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/sourcecode.html). It's written in C, but it [has a C# wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/freeimagecswrapper.aspx).